# Unable to attach matlab.exe process to visual studio 2013 for debugging mex files?

Tags: c++, matlab, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, remote-debugging

I am writing some mex files to run in my matlab program using visual studio 2013 compiler.
In order to be able to debug your mex files, you should follow [these steps](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/debugging-on-microsoft-windows-platforms.html)
Everything was right just some minutes ago and I was doing my project without any problem.
Today I have typed the code

```
mex -g mx_minimum_power.cpp cvm_em64t_debug.lib
```

on command prompt many times and after getting the success message, I've attached matlab.exe to visual studio and through setting a break point, I've 
debugged my code.
But this time I suddenly ran into the following error and I don't know how to solve it.
[image]

[image]

When I right-clicked on the third option and clicked `run as administrator`, I encountered the following message:
[image]

Then if I choose `configure remote debugging`, I'll encounter:
[image]

Now I have the following processes that are shown to be running.

[image]

and again:
[image]

When I click on permissions or options for remote debugger:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After running `visual studio remote debugging monitor` and getting the following message:

[image]

One should click the `Find` button in this window in order to find the `msvsmon.exe` that is being run on the subnet

[image]

and then choose `MATLAB.exe`, in the `Available Processes` list.

[image]